# Direction of current flow in circuit with multiple cells

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current, potential

[image: Circuit]

As the point $A$ is earthed we know that its potential is zero, same is true for point $B$. Due to the cell between $B$ and $C$ we can say that potential at $C$ is $-3V$. So the potential at point D is $-3V$. Due to the cell present between points $D$ and $E$, the potential at E is $-9V$.

Now we know that current flows from higher to lower potential. Due to the above established potentials, current should flow *from $B$ to $E$* and *from $D$ to $E$*. How is this possible that current only flows towards point $E$ and not away from it?

Answer (score 1):

> Now we know that current flows from higher to lower potential.

If the cell is discharging, the direction of current *externally* is from the more positive terminal to the more negative terminal. So, if the 6V cell is discharging, the current through the cell is directed *from* E *to* D.

This is what a [source of *emf* does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromotive_force#Overview) - it 'pumps' charge from a lower potential to a higher potential so that it can drive a current through an external circuit.

> A source of emf can be thought of as a kind of charge pump that acts
>   to move positive charges from a point of low potential through its
>   interior to a point of high potential. … By chemical, mechanical or
>   other means, the source of emf performs work dW on that charge to move
>   it to the high-potential terminal.

Answer (score 1):

> we know that current flows from higher to lower potential

This is not a general rule of nature, but rather a specific behavior of resistors. The cell is not a resistor and does not follow that behavior of resistors.